# Apache Spark with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I ran the below code:

```
object AirportsInUsaSolution {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("airports").setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val airports = sc.textFile("in/airports.text")
    val airportsInUSA = airports.filter(line => line.split(Utils.COMMA_DELIMITER)(3) == "\"United States\"")

    val airportsNameAndCityNames = airportsInUSA.map(line => {
      val splits = line.split(Utils.COMMA_DELIMITER)
      splits(1) + ", " + splits(2)
    })
    airportsNameAndCityNames.saveAsTextFile("out/airports_in_usa.text")
  }
}
```

And received the below error:

> Process finished with exit code 1

My final file that I used it to save my data in code is empty.

How can I solve it?
the program made correct file in right directory but it is empty

Comment: Looks like this is one of the exercises taken from Udemy course..please check your input file

Comment: change the line val airports = sc.textFile("in/airports.text") to val airports = sc.textFile("file:///in/airports.text") and it should work ?

Comment: @sathiyarajan no it did not work same as before but now atleast i know where is the problem i think files are the main problem but dont know how to fix it

Comment: @stack0114106 yes it is i download it from github and import with gradle in intellij i don not know all my files are local and all codes run by local CPU but i dont know why this happened